# Customize Search Portlet in Liferay DXP 7

Tags: search, autocomplete, portlet, customizing, liferay-7

I would like your support in order to get some help in customizing the search component in Liferay DXP 7.0 Enterprise.

I have reviewed all the available documentation but although I have found many articles about the issue, the step by step is not so clear for me.

I need to customize the native search component:

- Change the input component to give suggestions while the user is typing the search terms
- Change the search result page look and feel.

Anyone ever implemented anything like this?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but StackOverflow keeps showing it as the first open question when I am navigation this particular tag...So here are some pointers, as this is a pretty broad topic...

The search is really confusing for adding customization. Mainly you have to provide some of them as contributors, using the asset framework. following the regular steps to build an asset for the asset publisher you will hit the best place to find documentation about the search contributors.

About the search page, best is to create a new page, besides the default one for extra freedom. As long you use the friendly URL /search it will a basic replacement. In this page you can add everything you need, except for translations for the friendly URL - not great. Another option is to keep the default page (which will not be visible in the build area 7.1.x, but you can edit after you search something and fall inside it).